# Google assistant - error when deploy first app

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to deploy my first Actions on Google app. I'm using Dialogflow and Firebase Functions and deploying it using this command:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

But I'm getting the following messages and error:

```
=== Deploying to 'sillynamemaker-2369c'...

i  deploying functions i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled... i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled... ✔  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled ✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/fbfn_8461HDxPA7uUADKA/index.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Comment: You most likely just have a syntax error in your code, just as the error suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you edited any of the .js files? This error strongly suggests that it is trying to parse a JavaScript file, but you have a syntax error in something you entered.

If you type `node index.js` you may get a better idea where the syntax error is.

Comment: Do you think it would be on line 4, from `at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/fbfn_8461HDxPA7uUADKA/index.js:4:13)` in the stacktrace?